# Is it possible to only enable Agent Smith inspections in ReSharper?

Tags: c#, coding-style, resharper

We would like to have an intern go through our source files for spell checking and naming convention enforcement using the Agent Smith plug-in to ReSharper.  It would be very nice to minimize the "noise" from ReSharper inspections by disabling all inspection options except those provided by the Agent Smith plug-in.  Is this possible?

Comment: While it is possible to individually change the enabled state of inspections, we would prefer to toggle a single "flag" of some sort so that we don't lose our severity level configuration for current R# inspections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspections can be disabled in R#, so yes, this is possible.